# missing required positional arguments while calling member function via thread pool

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I wrote the following two methods, trying to benefit from multithreading:

```
class Data:

    def read_single_image(self, resample_size, index, image_directory_path):
        file_name = self.file_names[index]
        file_path = os.path.join(image_directory_path, file_name + '.*')
        files = glob.glob(file_path)
        if len(files) != 1:
            raise FileNotFoundError(errno.ENOENT, os.strerror(errno.ENOENT), file_path)
        image = misc.imread(file_path, mode='RGB')
        zoom = image.shape
        # image = interpolation.zoom(image_directory_path)
        zoom = (resample_size[0] / zoom[0], resample_size[1] / zoom[1], 1)
        image = interpolation.zoom(image, zoom)
        return image


    def read_images(self, resample_size, indice=None, image_directory_path=train_jpeg_directory_path):

        if indice is None:
            indice = self.shuffled_indice

        # reading all images into list
        images = []
        # for i in indice:
        #     image = self.read_single_image(resample_size, i, image_directory_path)
        #     images.append(image)
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(cpu_count()) as pool:
            for image in pool.map(self.read_single_image, [(resample_size, i, image_directory_path) for i in indice]):
                images.append(image)

        return np.stack(images)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with error message:

```
TypeError: read_single_image() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'index' and 'image_directory_path'
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

[`Executor.map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) (and consequently `ThreadPoolExecutor.map()`) takes an iterable and sends it over the enclosed pool one item per worker. This means that your `Data.read_single_image()` method gets called as: `self.read_single_image((resample_size, i, image_directory_path))` i.e. gets a `tuple` of all the arguments as the first argument (after the implied `self`) so it complains that it didn't receive the last two positional arguments.

You can remedy that by simply changing your `Data.read_single_image()` signature to: `Data.read_single_image(self, args)` and then read from the `args` tuple `resample_size` as `args[0]`, `index` as `args[1]` and `image_directory_path` as `args[2]`.

If you want to keep the signature as it is, you can write a proxy expander as:

```
def _read_single_image(self, args):
    return self.read_single_image(*args)
```

And call the `_read_single_image()` method from your `ThreadPoolExecutor.map()` instead (i.e. `pool.map(self._read_single_image, [(resample_size, i, image_directory_path) for i in indice])`)

Keep in mind that if you're going to perform some serious processing, you're much better off with the `multiprocessing` module, `ThreadPoolExecutor` is still somewhat limited by the dreaded GIL.